# Download azure files with cloud berry in folders

Tags: azure

I'm trying to download files from azure storage using cloud berry.  When I try to download a folder with many folders in it, it tries to bring over a file with the same name as the folder but with 0 bytes.

This makes the copy fail for any folders.

How can I download a folder with many sub folders without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

try with this program, in my case is very easy upload and download file, and you can download drive backups 
Azure Drive Explorer
http://azuredriveexplorer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Azure blobs are not a structured storage mechanism. So there are no directories, logical physical or otherwise. In order to make it easily distinguishable and addressable in a directory friendly way the blob storage allows naming files like **folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile.txt**. So if you are downloading a "folder" this is expected behavior. You need to download "all files" in the "folder" or rather all files which have the same preceding text that says they belong together. e.g.

- folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile1.txt
- folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile2.txt
- folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile3.txt

etc.